# How to fix : Unable to install xxxxx: authentication was required

Tags: 22.04, authentication, snap-store

Running 22.04.1 I was running constantly with an issue with the snap-store unable to refrsh, so I followed instructions to kill and refresh the store from the command line.

Since a few days, I can no longer install app from the snap store. It gives me an error : Unable to install [thisapp]:authentication was required.
I tried to uninstall the snap-store and reinstalling it, but no luck.
Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks,

Comment: nice how snap does not tell you on it's most annoying notifications to close the app without telling you which app , so you have to close all of them (guessing which ones are snap). seems the same for your error message "thisapp".